# Restarting Executors on restoring from Bundle

Tags: java, android, multithreading, reflection, parcelable

I am trying to put a `Parcelable` object that uses an `Executor` internally into a Bundle, but appearently the Bundle class copies the object by means of 
reflection instaid of using the `Parcelable` interface.

However this leaves the `Executor` in a corrupt state after restoring the object from the `Bundle`. Is there a good way to avoid this and make it so my `Executor` gets closed and recreated properly?`

This simpplyfied code illustrates my problem:

**Example main activity:**

```
public class MainSimple extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String KEY = "key";
    private MyObject object;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            object = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY);
        else
            object = new MyObject("State");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(KEY, object);
    }
}
```

**Object that has the `Executor` in it:**

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {
    private ExecutorService es;
    private String state;

    public MyObject(String state) {
        this.state = state;
        es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    protected MyObject(Parcel in) {
        //Not called when bundling
        state = in.readString();
        es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void run() {
        //do something with es
        es.submit(() -> Log.d("DEBUG","HELLO WORLD"));
    }

    public static final Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Creator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(state);
    }
}
```

When `MyObject` is reloaded from the `Bundle` the `Executor` doesn't work any more.

Comment: An Executor, which happens to be a thread of execution, is not parcelable therefore, you cannot not pass it with IPC. Threads are associated with a process. You cannot pass a thread from process-A to process-B. That's the simple explaination.

Comment: @edharned Yes I know, I am looking for a good way to close the `Executor` when the bundle saves it and open a new one when it restores it.

Comment: @Henrykvdb I am unable to understand, what your problem is, from contents of the question. Do you mean, that you call `run()`, but the message is not printed to log? Do you shutdown the executor at any point (why do you mention "closing and recreating" it)? What thread do you make the calls from? Either way, note that bundles are (de)serialized lazily: the system will not call `writeToParcel` until before passing the containing Bundle via IPC. It also might never invoke it (if the Bundle does not leave your process). This makes using them for any kind of lifecycle management highly unreliable.

Comment: @user1643723 Let me elaborate: I create a `MyObject` object and then save it to bundle. The issue is that when it loads again from bundle the `Executor` is broken (like it should be because you shouldn't save threads and restore them like this). So with broken I mean that run won't log anything after loading from bundle. I want to make sure my `Executor` is terminated before I save to bundle and create a new `Executor` when I restore from bundle. The issue is that apearently the  `Bundle` does not run the parcel constructor so I cannot just recreate the `Executor` there.

Comment: @Henrykvdb You cannot pass an Executor, period. Again, Executor is not parceable. You can have an Executor in process-A and an Executor in process-B. You just can't pass an Executor. Rewrite your code.

Comment: @edharned Like I said, I'm not trying to pass an `Executor`. I want to make my `Executor` close before my bundle saves the state and I want my object to create a new `Executor` when my object is restored from the `Bundle`. It doesn't matter if the new executor is not the old one.

Comment: @Henrykvdb  private ExecutorService es; is not parceable. You cannot pass the ExecutorService. You were talking about an Executor. What you meant was the ExecutorService. You need to rewrite the code without the ES.

Comment: @Henrykvdb do you call `shutdown()` of the Executor at any point?

Comment: @user1643723 I managed to resolve my problems by making game closable and not parcelable (this way Bundle won't try to save my `ExecutorService` with reflection, leaving them in a corrupt state). Now I made a `State` object containing all the nessesary info, which I then save to the bundle after calling the close method of `MyObject` (to ensure all `ExecutorService`'s are closed). On restore I just recreate the object with the state and in the constructor I make sure to start a new `ExecutorService`.